# How to change the Android app package name when assembling with Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to change the package name of an Android application using Gradle?

I need to compile two copies of the same app, having a unique package name (so I can publish to the market twice).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could so something like this

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        versionCode 10
    }

    flavorDimensions "flavor1", "flavor2"

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            applicationId "com.example.flavor1"
            versionCode 20
        }

        flavor2 {
            applicationId "com.example.flavor2"
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
}
```

You can also change the field `android.defaultConfig.applicationId` if you want to do one-off builds.

Taken from: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-Flavor-Configuration

Comment: For those wondering how to tell Gradle to build a particular flavour: By default all flavours are built, or you can specify one by running e.g. `gradle assembleFlavor1Debug` or `gradle assembleFlavor2Release`. `gradle tasks` is also helpful.

Comment: Hey should I need to copy java files from main/java to the flavor/java when changing the packageName using productFlavor?

Comment: I don't think so, but I have no data to support that guess.

Comment: Note that `packageName` was renamed `applicationId` (and `flavorGroups` => `flavorDimensions`) in [Android Gradle plugin version 1.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0). (Consider updating the answer.)

Comment: `packageName` is not the same as `applicationId`, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: So multiple apps with the same package string in the manifest, but different applicationIds can be uploaded to the Play Store?

Answer (score 76):

As a simpler alternative to using *product flavours* [as in Ethan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498565/56285), you can also customise *build types*.

How to choose between the approaches:

- If you need different package names to be able to have both *debug* and *release* apks installed on a device, then use the **build type** approach below, as [Gradle plugin docs agree](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types). In this case flavours are an overkill. (I think all projects should by default do this, as it will make life easier especially *after* you've published to the store and are developing new features.)
- There are valid uses for **product flavours**, the typical example being an app with free and paid versions. In such case, check [Ethan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498565/56285) and read the documentation too: [Configuring Gradle Builds](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants) and [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors).

(You can also combine the two approaches, which results in every *build variant* having distinct package name.)

#### Build type configuration

For *debug* build type, and all other non-*release* types, define `applicationIdSuffix` which will be added to the default package name.
(Prior to [Android Gradle plugin version 0.11](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio060released) this setting was known as `packageNameSuffix`.)

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        }

        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix '.beta'
            versionNameSuffix '-BETA'

            // NB: If you want to use the default debug key for a (non-debug) 
            // build type, you need to specify it:
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug 
        }

        release {
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // runProguard true
            // ...
        }

    }
}
```

Above, `debug` and `release` are default build types whose some aspects are configured, while `beta` is a completely custom build type. To build the different types, use `assembleDebug`, `assembleBeta`, etc, as usual.

Similarly, you can use `versionNameSuffix` to override the default version name from AndroidManifest (which I find very useful!). E.g. "0.8" → "0.8-BETA", as configured above.

Resources:

- This example is straight from Xavier Ducrohet's "[Google I/O 2013: The New Android SDK Build System](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0#t=9m15s)" presentation.
- [Build Types in the User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types).

Myself I've been using `productFlavors` so far for this exact purpose, but it seems build type customisation may be closer to my needs, plus it keeps the build config simpler.

**Update (2016)**: I've since used this approach in all my projects, and I think it definitely is the way to go. I also got it included in [Android Best Practices](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices) guide by Futurice.

Comment: Wow! thanks. Can I avoid the -debug-unaligned- and -release-unaligned- builds apks that are generated automatically by Gradle?

Comment: Well, yeah. If you do `gradle assembleDebug`, it will only produce `myapp-debug-unaligned.apk`. Building a custom type like `beta` above, `assembleBeta` will produce both `myapp-beta-unaligned.apk` and  `myapp-beta.apk` ([aligned i.e. optimised](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html)), *unless* you define `zipAlign false` for that type. See "The possible properties and their default values" in [User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types). I assume it's usually fine to only use zipAlign only for actual release builds.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote your answer twice! ;) thanks I'll try your solution

Comment: Another tip: when building with Android Studio, make sure you are aware [which build variant (type & flavour) is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656826/what-product-flavor-does-android-studio-build-by-default-in-build-gradle). (Perhaps obvious, but I just learned about it a few days ago. :)

Comment: I've a bad karma for AndroidStudio. I'll wait for a decent release. I'm using Eclipse and Gradle with batch. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: What do you do when you need GCM or other permission which depends on the application ID? e.g `<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.debug.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />. Any way to provide variables in androidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Nilzor: Sorry, I have no experience with that. Consider asking a new question.

Comment: The drawback of this approach (which is fine and should be used _in conjunction with the above_ is that Android won't let you have both (say BETA and DEBUG) installed at the same time, because the package is the same and the OS couldn't care less about the file name ;)

Comment: @MartínMarconcini: you might have misunderstood something. With `applicationIdSuffix` you specifically change the application ID (package name), which means you certainly **can** have beta and debug installed at the same time. *In addition*, my answer shows how to customise version name (which you might for example show inside the app) using `versionNameSuffix `.

Comment: @Jonik you're correct, I misread your post. This is the correct way to do it if you want to have qa/debug/releases build at the same time (useful when you're developing and you want to keep a release version side by side with your development version, to compare behaviors).

Comment: @Nilzor you can add this to your AndroidManifest:                              <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

Comment: For AndroidAnnotations users, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116644/android-annotations-and-applicationidsuffix) may also help.

Answer (score 10):

With the gradle plugin version of 1.0.0+ you have to use **applicationId** as stated in the [migration guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0)

> **Renamed Properties in ProductFlavors**
>
> packageName => applicationId

Thus in your build.gradle you would now use:

```
productFlavors {
   flavor1 {
      applicationId "com.example.flavor1"
   }

   flavor2 {
      applicationId "com.example.flavor2"
   } 
}
```

Comment: yes, see my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374933/android-studio-1-0-and-error-library-projects-cannot-set-applicationid/27376053#27376053

Answer (score 9):

From Ethan's answer, both flavorGroups and packageName both are not available anymore. Below works as of March 2015.

```
android {
...

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    versionCode 10
}

flavorDimensions "flavor"

productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        flavorDimension "flavor"
        applicationId "com.example.flavor1"
        versionCode 20
    }

    flavor2 {
        flavorDimension "flavor"
        applicationId "com.example.flavor2"
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, your response has already been posted! Please delete it before someone vote it down.

Comment: Hi @Seraphim's, sorry I don't see where it is posted in the thread. Can you please point me? I would be glad to delete.

Answer (score 2):

I did not want to use Flavors, so I found a way to do so with buildTypes. I did this by changing my `app/build.gradle` file as follows:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com" // See buildTypes.type.applicationIdSuffix
        ...
    }

    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".domain.name.debug"
            ...
        }
        releaseStaging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".compagny.staging"
            ...
        }
        release {
            applicationIdSuffix ".domain.name"
            ...
        }
    }
```

This allows me to have 3 apps next to each other on my devices.

I hope this helps others.