# How do I get different icons for the two versions of my GPS app generated via gradle build variants?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I want to have ONE Android Studio **(AS)** 1.1.0 project create TWO APK files: one for pay version and one for free version of my Google Play Store **(GPS)** app. Using gradle build variants ("flavors"). **I'm VERY close.** I have uploaded from one **AS** project both versions--free and pay.

The only relatively-minor problems: I can't make the two versions have different icons and I can't make the action bar display different titles for the different apps.

Since we're dealing with flavors, there are three `AndroidManifest.xml` files: one I CAN edit and two that gradle generates, one for each flavor. If I edit those, the edits are lost with the next build.

Here's "my" `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
package="com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants" >

<application


    android:icon="@drawable/kc_icon_free">


    android:label="@string/app_name"



    android:allowBackup="true"
>
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"




        android:icon="@drawable/kc_icon_free"




        android:name=".MyActivity"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Except for package name, the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` files are identical (here's one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants.pro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="KC" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants.MyActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/kc_icon_free"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I'm basing what I'm doing on this `build.gradle` file listed [here](http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html), which has outdated content, flagged with ///////////:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'  /////////(wrong version)
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 18
        }

        productFlavors {
            production {
                packageName "be.tamere.gradlebuildtypesexample"   ////// packageName should be applicationId
            }

            staging {
                packageName "be.tamere.gradlebuildtypesexample.staging"
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    }
```

Also basing my effort on this sketch of the associated file structure:

```
    +-- main
    ¦   +-- AndroidManifest.xml
    ¦   +-- ic_launcher-web.png
    ¦   +-- java
    ¦   ¦   +-- be
    ¦   ¦       +-- tamere
    ¦   ¦           +-- gradlebuildtypesexample
    ¦   ¦               +-- MainActivity.java
    ¦   +-- res
    ¦       +-- drawable-hdpi
    ¦       ¦   +-- ic_launcher.png
    ¦       +-- drawable-mdpi
    ¦       ¦   +-- ic_launcher.png
    ¦       +-- drawable-xhdpi
    ¦       ¦   +-- ic_launcher.png
    ¦       +-- drawable-xxhdpi
    ¦       ¦   +-- ic_launcher.png
    ¦       +-- layout
    ¦       ¦   +-- activity_main.xml
    ¦       +-- menu
    ¦       ¦   +-- main.xml
    ¦       +-- values
    ¦       ¦   +-- dimens.xml
    ¦       ¦   +-- strings.xml
    ¦       ¦   +-- styles.xml
    ¦       +-- values-v11
    ¦       ¦   +-- styles.xml
    ¦       +-- values-v14
    ¦           +-- styles.xml
    +-- production
    ¦   +-- java
    ¦       +-- be
    ¦           +-- tamere
    ¦               +-- gradlebuildtypesexample
    ¦                   +-- Constants.java
    +-- staging
        +-- java
        ¦   +-- be
        ¦       +-- tamere
        ¦           +-- gradlebuildtypesexample
        ¦               +-- Constants.java
        +-- res
            +-- drawable-hdpi
            ¦   +-- ic_launcher.png
            +-- drawable-mdpi
            ¦   +-- ic_launcher.png
            +-- drawable-xhdpi
            ¦   +-- ic_launcher.png
            +-- drawable-xxhdpi
            ¦   +-- ic_launcher.png
            +-- values
                +-- string.xml
```

I don't know if lack of "|" symbols from staging on down is significant. If so, that could be where I'm diverging.

When I try to create both APKs, I eventually get this screen, which is great news:

[image]

Inside AS, I see this, which is great news:

[image]

And in Windows 7 Explorer I see:

[image]

Here's my structure inside AS:

[image]

This corresponds to the structure shown in the link. Note especially NO `res` folder in the `free` version. The `res` folder in `main` contains the icon for `free` version. The `res` folder in `pro` contains the icon for `pro` version.

**How can I get different icons for the two different APKs?**

**Why does the title in the action bar for both versions show as a fully-qualified package name?**

**Is there a way to edit the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` files? Or to make each flavor have its own editable `AndroidManifest.xml`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't make the two versions have different icons and I can't make the action bar display different titles for the different apps.

Step #1: Choose one (free or paid) to be the one you have in the `main/` sourceset. For the purposes of this answer, I'll assume that the free one goes in `main/`.

Step #2: Edit `main/res/values/strings.xml` to have your desired free edition of the `app_name` resource, as you are using the `app_name` string resource in your manifest.

Step #3: Create a `paid/res/values/strings.xml` with a definition of `app_name` that contains your desired value for the `paid` app's display name.

Step #4: Decide whether you are going to use mipmaps or drawables for your launcher icon. You seem to have mipmap directories, but your manifest references a drawable resource. For the purposes of this answer, I will assume that you will go with mipmaps.

Step #5: Decide what you are going to call the launcher icon. Your app presently does not build, it would appear, as your manifest refers to a `kc_icon_free` drawable, but your directory listing shows `ic_launcher`. In particular, you want the name to **NOT** refer to "free" or "paid". I will assume here that you go with `ic_launcher`.

Step #6: Get your icons and manifest reorganized per the above, with your free edition of the icons in the `main` sourceset.

Step #7: Create `paid/res/mipmap-*/` directories and put the paid edition of `ic_launcher` icons in there.

> Since we're dealing with flavors, there are three AndroidManifest.xml files: one I CAN edit and two that gradle generates, one for each flavor. If I edit those, the edits are lost with the next build.

You are certainly welcome to have `AndroidManifest.xml` files in the `free` and `paid` sourcesets. They will get merged with the one in `main`, the Gradle settings, and manifests from any dependencies.

That being said, you don't need that here. Have one manifest, pointing to one set of resources for labels and icons. Have one edition of the labels and icons in the `main` sourceset; have the other in a product flavor's sourceset (e.g., `paid` per my steps above).

> Why does the title in the action bar for both versions show as a fully-qualified package name?

Presumably, that is what you have for the `app_name` string resource value. If you do not like it, change the string resource.

> Is there a way to edit the generated AndroidManifest.xml files?

Not the merged ones.

> Or to make each flavor have its own editable AndroidManifest.xml?

See above. Again, that's not the right solution for your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare--WOW. What a nice reply. It'll take awhile to go through the ton of files and contents in my mess and apply what you've said to it, but I'm betting you have told me exactly what I need. When I get it to work, yours is The Answer. Thanks for wading through my lengthy question. (I wasn't sure if I should include the structure and gradle build from the link since it's not mine and could confuse, but you seem to have gotten through it.)

Comment: @CommonsWare--one down, one to go. Rather than edit original post, I've provided an "Answer" for ease of showing what I have in terms of the `app_name` situation, still not resolved. I will do away with "my Answer" one way or another after I finally fix app_name.

Comment: @CommonsWare--TWO DOWN, ZERO TO GO. I hadn't put the reference to `app_name` inside `Activity` but inside `Application`. NO PROBLEMS! THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a picture of what I had been stuck on that @CommonsWare so completely clarified:

[image]

Each with different `app_name`:

[image]

`Gradle` disambiguates both via `ProductFlavors` block declarations:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
{
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig
    {
        applicationId "com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes
    {
        release
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    productFlavors
    {
        pro
        {
            applicationId "com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants.pro"
        }
        free
        {
            applicationId "com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants.free"
        }
    }
}

dependencies
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

And here is the `MyActivity.java` reference to BOTH variants:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  boolean FREE = Free.FREE;
```

Depending on how the value of FREE is set in each variant, the variant is either "free" (FREE = true) or "pro" (FREE = false). Here are those two variant classes, both named `Free` in their respective files:

In `KakuroCombosBuildVariants\app\src\free\java\com\dslomer64\kakurocombosbuildvariants\Free.java`:

```
package com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants;

public class Free
{
  public static final boolean FREE = true;
}
```

In `KakuroCombosBuildVariants\app\src\pro\java\com\dslomer64\kakurocombosbuildvariants\Free.java`:

```
package com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants;

public class Free
{
  public static final boolean FREE = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the ''Ribbonizer plugin for Android'', written by FUJI Goro.

This is a ribbonizer as a Gradle plugin for Android, which adds a ribbon to launcher icons automatically.

https://github.com/gfx/gradle-android-ribbonizer-plugin