# Android annotations and applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

I'd been trying out [Android annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) recently and everything had been working well until I decided to add `applicationIdSuffix` in `buildTypes` in my `build.gradle` file. Currently it looks like this:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
    }

    ...
}
```

And upon compiling I get the following log in gradle console:

> :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>     :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:pre_testBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   No matching client found for package name 'org.me.myapp.debug'
>   :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   Note: Resolve log file to /dir/myapp/app/build/generated/source/apt/androidannotations.log
>   Note: Initialize AndroidAnnotations 3.3.1 with options {androidManifestFile=/dir/myapp/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml}
>   Note: Start processing for 4 annotations on 18 elements
>   Note: AndroidManifest.xml file found with specified path: /dir/myapp/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>   Note: AndroidManifest.xml found: AndroidManifest [applicationPackage=org.me.myapp.debug, componentQualifiedNames=[org.me.myapp.ui.MainActivity_, net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity], permissionQualifiedNames=[android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE], applicationClassName=null, libraryProject=false, debugabble=false, minSdkVersion=15, maxSdkVersion=-1, targetSdkVersion=22]
>   error: The generated org.me.myapp.debug.R class cannot be found
>   Note: Found Android class: android.R
>   Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 15 ms], [Extract Manifest = 4 ms], [Extract Annotations = 3 ms],
>   Note: Finish processing
>   Note: Start processing for 0 annotations on 0 elements
>   Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 0 ms],
>   Note: Finish processing
>   1 error
>   FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding again, removing `generated` directory from the project, but nothing helps. If I remove `applicationIdsuffix` from `build.gradle` file, everything works fine. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove this line from your `build.gradle` file:

```
resourcePackageName android.variant.applicationId
```

**Edit**: try to add this line to your `apt` block:

```
resourcePackageName "org.me.myapp"
```

Comment: I don't have anywhere this line.

Comment: or "resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId" to avoid using hardcoded values

Comment: But my problem was solved by giving correct value for applicationId in defaultConfig of app level build.gradle

Comment: Yes,  you need the default app id, it does not matter how you pass it. The original problem here was the per variant app id was used. Actually AA needs the manifest package, not the app id,  but most of the time the manifest package is the same as the default app id.

Comment: @WonderCsabo do you know how configurate this but fopr the new annotationProcessor. I'm not using apt

Comment: @rkmax please read [this](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/1853) thread.

Answer (score 22):

For me this was happening because `google-services.json` was referring to my production package name. The best solution at the time of this writing seems to be to either write your own gradle tasks to switch between `release` and `debug` versions of the file, or to include both package names in the file:

[google-services.json for different productFlavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors)