# How to upload an apk multiple times to play store?

Tags: android, google-play, package, google-play-services

Think I have built and APK, 
the unique change is some resources, that's all
this is not a new version, this is a new apk (or a new app)

How can I upload those apks to play store?
My project is divided in multiple layers (I believe every layer is a package, isn't it? ) then, do I must to rename every package?

What changes do I must to do for upload it as a new apk (app).
Do I need to change something in gradle file? in manisfest?
rename ALL packages and subpackages?

what is the easy way to rename package and subpackage 
what is the easy way for upload same project (diferent app or apk ) to play store (where only change some resource).

Can I use my finished project as a java library (or module) and create new apps (so maybe I avoid rename packages)

This is not my project ( I have it now in other pc)
But in the next image (took from wikipedia) You see a package where in my real project I have multiple sub-packages, 
then isn't it necesary rename them?

[image]

best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Think I have built and APK, the unique change is some resources,
>   that's all this is not a new version, this is a new apk (or a new app)

Package name of your apk is your id in Play Store, every time that you change your apk package name you create a new app, even having the same resources inside.

> How can I upload those apks to play store? My project is divided in
>   multiple layers (I believe every layer is a package, isn't it? ) then,
>   do I must to rename every package?

Your internal java package name in your project is just for your internal code structure. There is no need to change internal java package name when you change your apk package name in AndroidManifest.xml

> What changes do I must to do for upload it as a new apk (app). Do I
>   need to change something in gradle file? in manisfest? rename ALL
>   packages and subpackages?

As I said in the first point you only need to change AndroidManifest.xml package name a

> Can I use my finished project as a java library (or module) and create
>   new apps (so maybe I avoid rename packages)

Yes, there is a lot of questions in SO related to custom android library to share content, activities between projects

**EDIT:** You can change your apk package name in your build.gradle.
Check this link for more info:

- [ApplicationId versus PackageName](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename)
- [How to change the Android app package name when assembling with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491649/how-to-change-the-android-app-package-name-when-assembling-with-gradle)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I am a little confused, because everyone say me "you need change the package for upload it again", but  what files are package then? manifest only? or every folder with I added as "add new package" in android studio?, when everyone say change package I thought in every folder and subfolder.

Comment: Apk package name is the element package="your.app.package.name.xxx" inside your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Java project package is to organize your code inside your project, is not related to AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: please if the answer is valuable for you mark the question as solved :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103132/discussion-between-angel-and-g2o).

Comment: hey again, I have upload my first app in playstore.. but now I am more confused, other developers said me the package is (the structure code) see it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350946/what-is-the-package-in-android

Comment: Java projects are structured in package or *folder* if you want to call in other way, you can open your android project in your explorer and you'll see it. 
Your question should be titled "What is package in AndroidManifest.xml?"...the package that you define in your question is your aplicationId, as I try to explain you later, there is no need that your applicationId or AndroidManifest.xml package be named equals to your structure java folder. Sorry I want to make you a clear sample with picture but right now I dont have time. I hope you understand :)

Comment: Thanks, in manifest (with package it did not work) it work in gradle with id. I have uploaded 2 apps now :)