# How to change package name android studio for reupload as a new app (not new version)?

Tags: android, android-studio, package, android-manifest, manifest

I had done a question in this pack for know what do I need to change for upload my project multiple time to google playstore.

I got in the answer: I only need to rename the packagename which is in manifest.
Now I have tried but I got many errors (for imports in R.string.xxx)

This is the link [How to upload an apk multiple times to play store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296589/how-to-upload-an-apk-multiple-times-to-play-store)

then how can I change the packagename correctly?

I want to create multiples apks diferentes ( I he updated some resources and this create a new apk now a new version)

I am working using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Once you publish your application under its manifest package name, this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.

However, application package name and packages for your classe are different. If you want to change your packages class architecture, use the refactor function within Android Studio then clean your build and it should work (even for R. class which is a generated class).

Comment: I havent uploaded an app yet, I change the packagename in manifest, but I got several errors (about R.class for imports was referenced to the old pachagename) I changed them manually and this runs. is there some way  for I dont change them manually(imports referencing to new packagename) ??

Comment: Refactor > change name