# What is the package in android?

Tags: android, package, android-manifest, manifest

I have uploaded my first application to google playstore
as you see in this image in manifest in package it says auc.visorimagenes.ssssss

in the left part you could see my structure code where it is as
auc.visorimagenes.

[image]

in playstore
you see it:

[image]

but What it says `auc.visorimagenes`
if in my manifest I had set `auc.visorimagenes.sssss`

I want to up a new app with same code (only changing some resources) this is would be a new app not an update.

then I must to change `auc.visorimagenes.sssss` ???

Answer (score 0):

The package in android is the name of the application that makes it unique from any other android apps, therefore allow the production of multiple apps with the same product name.

Comment: but where is it? in my example what is the package?

Comment: @angel The package name is the highlighted bit in the hierarchy and can be renamed by right clicking on it and chosing refactor then rename.

Comment: Now I am more confusing, in this answer some said me the package name is on manifest, if I want to upload my app as a new app (not as an update) I just need to change the package in manifest. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296589/how-to-upload-an-apk-multiple-times-to-play-store

Comment: what do I need to change then, for upload it as a new app? (based in the images I have uploaded)

Comment: @angel Take it off the app store using the Developers Console the Re-upload it with the correct Package name.

Comment: I dont what to take it off, I want to know for upload a new application (created from same code, I just change resources) what Do I need to change? is it on manifest? or is it doing refactoring in structure code? what?? for upload a new app, not an update from first app.

Comment: First you rename the bit package selected in the hierarchy of your picture (The bit on the left) and rename it by right clicking it and choosing refactor then rename, Then you can upload it to the app store.

Comment: then this auc.visorimagenes.sssss in manifest is not the package? I need to do that you have said (refactoring)for re-upload the app (as new app)

Comment: Does it Work angel ?

Comment: I haven tried, I would tried later... But now I have understood I have change the package (structure of my code)  the bit on the left in the image, but then what is "package" in manifest.xml?

Comment: I will upload other app generate from same code (I have generate the apk) but for the time I could not upload it today.

Comment: it does not work. I got next message "apk already exist, please change name it" then  I changed it in gradle...  
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "auc.visorimagenes.newname"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }   and this works.

Comment: You can delete your answer, but don't "vandalize" it.

Answer (score 0):

Contains information about a Java package. This includes implementation and specification versions. Typically this information is retrieved from the manifest.

Packages are managed by class loaders. All classes loaded by the same loader from the same package share a Package instance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to understant, in my example, what is tha packege (Unique Id application for playstore) because I dont know what is (In my example).

Comment: In your example, package is simply just the codename of your AndroidManifest.

Comment: then I change this name auc.visorimagenes.sssss for this auc.visorimagenes.xxxxx and Could I upload a new app? (as new app not as an update of first app)

Comment: other thing, what in playstore appears auc.visorimagenes and not auc.visorimagenes.sssss??

Answer (score 0):

Could you try and change the android:name attribute of your application entry in the manifest as follows and see if it helps?

```
<application
   ....
   android:name=".App"  (or android:name=".Application.App")
 />
```

This will ensure that the app uses the same package name as the one declared in the manifest.