# Google Play upload problem: "Your Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.x.x.base"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I am trying to upload an application under development to Google Play Console, internal testing track. The application has two flavor dimensions and and two dynamic features, the last two being resources only (no code). I am relying on Android Studio to generate the directory structure and the signed bundle.

The name of the package is com.something.something. The upload fails  with the message "Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.something.something.base."

I cannot track down the source of the problem, though it looks like it should have something to do with the flavor dimensions. On the other hand, I had no problem uploading a single apk, without the dynamic features.

I am not sure which part of the code is relevant here, which is probably part  of my problem, but my main build gradle looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.something.something'
        ....
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            //testCoverageEnabled false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        small {
            dimension "version"
        }
        full {
            dimension "version"
        }
    }

    dynamicFeatures = [":feat1", ":feat2"]

}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

I do not want to burden the question with irrelevant code, but can provide more if there is some intuition about where the problem might be.

I would be grateful for any suggestion on how to approach the debugging here. (Uploading is painfully slow, trial and error is not much of an option.)

Answer (score 6):

Thank you all for taking a shot at the answer. Here is what I learned about this issue and how I "solved" it.

My problem starts with Google Play Console (GPC) insisting  that [an app name  be associated with the very first package name you have uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45434201/5197488). This is in addition to having [one app = one package name rule](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#Rules). If you are still in the draft stage, you can delete the package from your "All applications" list in GPC, and upload a package with different name, but once it's published - no such luck. The way GPC is designed, all my future uploads should have the suffix ".base", if this is what my first upload had.

Next, Android Studio (AS), does something called [manifest file merging](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html). (@Fantômas, your audience may not be as omniscient as you are - the behavior of AS is relevant here, and with your permission I would return the tag.) When you choose the flavor for the bundle, the name of the flavor is suffixed to create the  package name in the merged AndroidManifest file, irrespective of the name you specify in your main AndroidManifest.xml, as you can check if you choose to "analyze" (the name of the link after the bundle is generated) newly created bundle:

[image: screenshot of android Studio with bundle contents open]

Thus, in my first upload I had a flavor called base, and I did not realize that AS tacked it as the suffix on the name of my package.  From that point on, GPC will not take a package for my app by any other name.

One thing that *is* irrelevant here are dynamic features - they just happened to be part of my second upload attempt.

I have asked Google to delete my app so I can start from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to delete your app from Google console. Simply open `Build.gradle(Module:app)` in your android studio and change the Application Id to the name google is requesting from you.

Comment: But when you upload this to Google Play, they tell you to have the previous package name, so downvote from me

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem is not related to codes, try changing your package name to something else, something more "unique". 
com.myname.myappname is an example. In this case you need to change everything related to your package name. Try it and report back

Comment: "Uploading is painfully slow, trial and error is not much of an option."

Comment: He says Google told him it's a package problem. And I couldn't comment. So basically, changing the package name to com.myname.android.myappname is a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your Application Id in your Build.Gradle(Module: app)

You may also need to change the name in your google-services.json file under this section:

```
"client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "...",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.yourpackagename.yourpackagename"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

good coding!!

You can avoid "Manifest file merging" (of Android Studio...) to altering the package name of the "merged manifest" in the build variant, by excluding the applicationIdSuffix definition on the build type or flavour dimmension definition in the build.gradle (app: module), like in my following example, in what I want to avoid to adding the respective package name suffixes ".release" and ".full" in my "release" and/or "full" versions of my App:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // applicationIdSuffix ".release"
            versionNameSuffix "-release"
        }
        debug {
            proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }
    }

    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        free {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".free"
            versionNameSuffix "-free"
        }
        full {
            dimension "version"
            // applicationIdSuffix ".full"
            versionNameSuffix "-full"
        }
    }
```

Regards,

P.D.:
And thanks a lot for all the other answers, that help me in this moment to take this my decission of doing the above posted... Thanks, especially for @celaeno, that explained how works the "Manifest merging" in Android Studio, and over all, advertised how App Id SUFFIXES may CHANGE the App.Id in Google Play Console terms...

Answer (score 0):

change the applicationId in android/app/build.gradle to the same id of the previos versions.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxxxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 12
    versionName "3.2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    targetSdkVersion 30
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, pay attention to which flavor of your application you are building, since some of them might have set

```
applicationIdSuffix
```