# Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.voca.abc

Tags: android, google-play-console

this is one of app i have developed couple of years ago and i need to update the apk with new features and following error message pops me out from the google play consol

```
Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.voc
```

and my project manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.voca.abc">
```

and build gradle (module app)

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.voca.abc'
}
```

and folder stucture also in same. any help appriciate.

NOTE: I copied the ziped project source from my external hard drive to my working pc

thanks in-advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648188/google-play-upload-problem-your-android-app-bundle-needs-to-have-the-package-n

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: Install the app on your device and check the package name on your device.
Edit: I realized, that you can't see the package name from the app settings anymore. So you will need to use the ADB shell to list all installed packages.

Comment: i did not get you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by removing the `applicationId` inside the `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationId
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I feel like Android would require the applicationID

Comment: What do you mean ? You told to remove the `applicationId` , but added it inside `buildTypes`