# Changing application name in Play Store Console for draft application

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

In Google Play Console, I created a new app and uploaded an application bundle for internal testing.

Play Console set my app's application name to the `applicationId` field of my build.gradle file, which is not the application name I want it to have (lets say `com.wrongName.app`).

I want to change the application name, but if I upload a new application bundle, I get:

```
Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.wrongName.app
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648188/google-play-upload-problem-your-android-app-bundle-needs-to-have-the-package-n) seems to imply that I can still delete the app bundle and load a new one, since this is still a draft. But I see no way to delete an app bundle, or even delete my app.

Am I stuck with the wrong application name?

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can delete the app bundle, and delete the app as well. There is a provision in the Play Console for that. The Package name has to be identical to your App Name as well, without which you will not be able to upload it.

Comment: That's good news.  Where in the play console is the ability to delete the app bundle?

I spent a lot of time looking for that and couldn't find it.

Comment: click on the app, go to Advanced Settings, and click on "unpublish", it will remove the app from the playstore, and then u can add a new app

Comment: I don't have an unpublish button under 'Advanced Settings'.  I just have some sections (App availability, Release Types, etc.), which don't really have content. I don't think my app is technically "published" as I only loaded an AAB into internal testing.

Comment: yeah so u can just delete the release, if u havent yet published it