# How do you install the dev version and release version of your android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

On my phone I have my release version of my app installed, I also want to install my development version alongside it. When I try to do so in android studio by running the app to my phone, I get

```
The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
```

After trying to rename the app debug version of the app, I still get this error. Is it possible to have both release and dev version of the app installed at the same time?

Comment: basically no you can't.   You're going to have to uninstall before installing the publish version.
And really how could you?  Your app specifies the file structure where it's installed.  They would overwrite each other.  And i should warn you before some of the ruder members find your posting:  "can i" questions ALWAYS get downvoted.

Comment: Actually! I found the solution in a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491649/how-to-change-the-android-app-package-name-when-assembling-with-gradle

Comment: ok well i stand corrected.  I didn't know we could append to the folder names like that.  I should still suggest you delete your post though because now it's also in danger of being flagged as duplicate.