# Over 64k Methods Non-Multidex Debug Solution

Tags: java, android

I came across the issue stated in the title that my app hit the 64k method references limit. After searching SO, I have realized the limitation on `DEX` files. My issue is only related to debug mode only. On release, I have a small fraction of the number of methods, so no problem there.

I want to be able to debug my app without having to turn `multidex` on. I have seen people suggest enabling `multidex` only on debug. Though, I have read that having `multidex` enabled will have issues when debugging on pre API21 devices. So, I am trying to avoid it.

I am testing out the following:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

My idea is to use minimification on debug as I do release. Will this fix cause me any issues in the long run? Also, is it possible to use different rules for debug?

Thanks.

Comment: " I have read that having multidex enabled will have issues when debugging on pre API21 devices"  - what issues? This works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read that on a different question. They also mentioned that `multidex` slows down pre API21 devices. May I ask if you use multidex on your products?

Comment: Of course. `minifyEnabled` means a many minute wait for every build. Seems terrible for development.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You gave me something to think about. Now, I am considering using multidex for debugging. Will using multidex for debugging be faster than using `minifyEnabled true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`My idea is to use minimification on debug as I do release.`

Yes, simply minify your application. This will dramatically reduce the number of library methods. This is how many companies including mine reduce both the size of our App Bundles and method counts. Simply set minifyEnabled to true as you have set on your specified gradle file.

`Do you use minifyEnabled true for debug, too, to bypass the 64k on debug builds?`

You are not bypassing the 64k when you set minifyEnabled true, you are eliminating all of the methods that you do not use from your build. I would only set it to true if you are doing some final testing on your debug build for Release. This is because your build times will be insanely long if setting the minifyEnabled value to true on your debug build all the time

`Will this fix cause me any issues in the long run?`

No, if you provide the correct Proguard rules, your application should completely be fine. Proguard may be daunting, but with the new release of Android Studio and also, the countless amount of Proguard articles online, you should be fine. Some common cases you should definitely look into while applying Proguard are:

- Apply rules to protect your reflection based code
- Apply rules to protect your Kotlin enumerators
- Look at each of your libraries and make sure you go to their github API page and ensure you are applying any library specific rules. Some popular example libraries include Glide and Koin

`Also, is it possible to use different rules for debug?`

I am assuming you mean whether you can apply different Proguard rules to debug. Yes, you can see that you can specify the proguard rules files in which you want to pull the rules from, simply create a new file with rules that you want to apply for debug mode

Comment: I am sorry but I want to make sure I understood this right. Do you use `minifyEnabled true` for debug, too, to bypass the 64k on debug builds? Also, I want to understand the proguard rules line. I know `proguard-rules.pro` is the filename, but I do not understand the 'proguard-android.txt' portion. If I was to create separate rules for debug should be my line be like `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-debug-rules.pro'` (for example) keeping 'proguard-android.txt' as is? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, as you specified, you would simply create a new proguard-debug-rules.pro file. However, the way I do this is simply comment out/commend back in pieces of Proguard rules (such as leaving obfuscation on/off) as I move back and forth from debug and release builds.

Comment: I have edited the post to answer your first question in your comment

Comment: Thank you for the information. About the debug `minifyEnabled true` option. I am bit confused. You said that you only use it for final phase debug testing. What do you do on day to day debugging? I mean if you hit the 64k limit, you will not be able to debug the app on your devices unless you reduce the methods by normal means or by using `minifyEnabled true` or by using the `multidex ` option. Do you perhaps not perform day to day debugging, or is there something I have missed?

Comment: It doesn't matter on my end as the minimum sdk of the application I am building is higher than 21, in which multidex is enabled by default. Minify(ing) your dev build makes your build times longer and longer as your application becomes more complex/modular where you have multiple minify processes running because of your modules. Speeding up build times are beyond the scope of this question however, and there are many resources online such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776671/speed-up-gradle-build-in-multidex-application